# float every other item in a definition list

Tags: css

Greetings all.

I have a definition list like so:

```
<dl>
 <dd>This is an item on a new line</dd>
 <dd class="float_even">This item should sit on a new line</dd>
 <dd class="float_odd">This item should float next to the previous item</dd>
 <dd class="float_even">This item should sit on a new line</dd>
 <dd class="float_odd">This item should float next to the previous item</dd>        
 <dd>This is an item on a new line</dd>
</dl>
```

The following css works in Firefox:

```
dd { clear:both; }
dd.float_even { float:left; }
dd.float_odd { float:left; clear:none; }
```

...but fails in IE(6/7/8). The ".float_odd" items both occupy the same line as the first ".float_even" item.

I'm trying to get the ".float_even" and ".float_odd" items to occupy the same line, and all other items to occupy their own lines. The items have variable and unknown width.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you should use `dd { clear:left; }` using clear:both should place the dd on a line of its own.

I think the best way to do what you want to do here is:

```
dl { width: 400px; }
dd { width: 200px; float: left; overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Johan. The items have unknown and variable width, so I can't set the width property.

Comment: Hmm, too bad.. The next best thing is to add extra dd elements to break the line.. I don't think the clearing trick will work in IE6/7/8

Answer (score 0):

Removing the float on dd.float_odd did the trick. Cheers!